# how can I center my menu bar?

Tags: html, css, menubar

I need to center the menu bar. i have trie everything i think.

here are the source files of the MENU BAR ;

http://insicdesigns.com/downloads/fancy-menu.zip

i try the following code

```
<align=center>
```

but it doesnt work.

I will center all the contents at the center of the page. now it is on the left.

how can I make this exactly ? I am a beginner and want to help.

Comment: Can you post some code or a fiddle plz

Comment: can you create a fiddle rather than expecting us to unzip the files and figure out where you are going wrong?

Comment: `align` and its properties have been depreciated for a very long time, maybe it's time to look up some best practices with CSS?

Comment: you can see it via the link i have given.

Answer (score 0):

use the css text-align property :
text-align:center
see how it works here :
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp
hoping it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Your markup looks pretty basic but a id tag in your html

```
<h1 id="header">
```

and some css

```
#header {
    text-aligh: center;
}
```

should do. or you can try using

```
margin: auto 0;
```

on a div that is the width of the text.